# How to make Watson Visual Recognition identify each object?

Tags: image, watson, visual-recognition

When i submit a picture with a few vegetables grouped together, it does not return the name of each vegetables. However, it works fine if I seperate the vegetables into different pictures to be recognized.

How can i make it return with the name of each vegetables? Or do i need to use custom classifier? But watson already knows the vegetables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A valid approach to tackle this problem is the use of sliding windows to create smaller subimages out of one image containing multiple entities.

A good example can be found [here](https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/Visual-Recognition-Tile-Localization) on GitHub.

Here's a video showing a sliding window approach in action https://youtu.be/wEs1imQmk-Y

Answer (score 0):

There is no way with Watson visual recognition to tell the system a number of objects to look for. The closest thing you can do is segment the image into pieces and submit each piece.